# Use Hölder's Inequality to get $(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^p+(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i)^p \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i^p+y_i^p)^{1/p}\right)^p$

Tags: proof-verification, alternative-proof, holder-inequality

It appears that an inequality of this kind has been used [here](https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2017/09/23/lecture-8-rough-paths-fall-2017/). Note: both sequences ($x_i$ and $y_i$) are non-negative, and $p\geq 1$.

In fact, the author then claims that last expression is less than or equal to
$$(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i+ y_i)^p.$$

I think I've been able to verify this claim: if we call
$$a:=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$
and
$$b:=\sum_{i=1}^n y_i$$
then the claim becomes
$$a^p+b^p\leq (a+b)^p.$$

I think I can prove this as follows:
\begin{align*}
(a^p+b^p)^{1/p}=&\left((a^{1/p}a^{1-1/p})^p+(b^{1/p}b^{1-1/p})^p\right)^{1/p}\\
\leq& \max\{a,b\}^{1-1/p}(a+b)^{1/p}\\
\leq &(a+b)^{1-1/p}(a+b)^p\\
= &a+b.
\end{align*}

Raising both sides to the power of $p$ establishes the claim.

However, I haven't used Hölder's inequality, or the intermediate step (which I included in the title). Can you see what the author has done?